# Update Reading Source after Writing Step

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch

We have a huge table "clients" in postgresql database that have a lot of duplicated content. So I have created a Spring batch to merge duplicated client into one based on their email.

I have a reading step that reads from this table (with a custom query that target only clients with at least a single duplication) then in the processing step I gather all information and in the writing step I delete the duplicated client and keep only the one where I merged all information.

```
 @Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<Client> clientFusionReader(
            ClientRepository clientRepository
    ) {
        return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<Tiers>()
                .methodName("findClientsWithPhoneAndEmailNotNullAndNonDuplicated")
                .sorts(Collections.singletonMap("update_date", Sort.Direction.ASC))
                .repository(clientRepository)
                .pageSize(100)
                .name("BATCH_MERGE_CLIENT_READER")
                .build();
    }
```

The problem I have currently is that Spring batch does not read the table after I delete the rows so I still have the old items getting processed and in the delete step an exception is raised as the item don't exist anymore.

Is there a way to refresh the reading source after the writing step so that I avoid process deleted items that Spring batch keep in memory after reading?

UPDATE 1 :

Here is my job configuration :

```
 @Bean
    public Step clientFusionStep(RepositoryItemReader<Client> clientFusionReader) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("fusionClientStep")
                .<Client, ClientOutput>chunk(100)
                .reader(clientFusionReader)
                .processor(clientFusionProcessor)
                .writer(clientFusionWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(Step clientFusionStep) {
        return jobs.get("fusionClientJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(clientFusionStep)
                .preventRestart()
                .build();
    }
```

First step, I'm reading from database taking all records that are at least duplicated once, in the processor I look for related tables to client so that if I delete a client I need to delete all table related to it and in the final step of writing I'm deleting the duplicated clients.

Once I arrive to writing step, I want refresh the datasource so that I take in consideration the updates I did. Because in second chunk I get deleted clients and the batch is processing them.

Comment: How many steps do you have? Can you share your job configuration and explain what each step is supposed to do?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I've added more details and my job configuration.

Comment: Your job has a single step called `clientFusionStep`. What you are calling step (reading step, processing step and writing step) is not an actual step within a job. You are deleting records from the same table you are reading from at the same time with a paging reader. I'm not sure you can achieve what you are trying to do in a single chunk-oriented step. Is it an option for you to mark records for deletion with a flag in your `clientFusionStep` and add a second tasklet step to delete those records?

Comment: Yes. I have no problem adding a tasklet to delete records. I'm already persisting IDs of all clients I delete so I can read that table in tasklet and delete.
But will this actually solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, because your chunk-oriented step will be "side-effect" free, ie it won't delete records.  Since you are saving the IDs of the records to delete, you can issue a delete query with those IDs in a subsequent step.